# Formatting Javamail Body

Tags: css, jakarta-mail, html-email, tabular

I have implemented mail body like this. The code segment is like:

```
messageBodyPart.setContent("<h1 style=\"color:blue;\">You Have a Promotion </h1> <h4><b>Your First Name :</b></h4>" + FirstNm + 
                          "<h4>Your Last Name :</h4>" + LastNm + "<h4>Your Employee ID :</h4>" + Employeeid + 
                          " <br/> <form>\r\n" + 
                                "<a href=\"http://localhost:8080/update/status/password/ACCEPT\"><input class=\"MyButton\"  type = \"button\" value =\"Accept Your Promotion\" /></a>\r\n" + 
                          "</form>","text/html");
```

So following is the body of the mail look like this:

[image]

What I want is the data to appear in a table manner. It means **First Name : Wahalathanthrige likewise.**  Thus better data can be formatted into a table. Any suggestions?

Comment: Well then create a table, instead of headlines followed by text …? Not sure what your actual question/ problem is here to be honest.

Comment: Actually what i want is in the attached image there is a tag called Your First name then after leaving the line has: Wahalathanthrige. what i want is Wahalathanthrige need to be appear in the same line with the Your First name

Comment: Well then _don’t_ use a block element like `h4` for “Your First name”, or add styling to it to make it inline.

Comment: So that can we bold  or size up the fonts?

Comment: There’s lots of other ways to achieve that … (and choosing the HTML element to use based on what you want things to _look_ like is rather the wrong approach to begin with.) It seems your question has very little to do with sending an email in itself, and is more or less just a rather basic HTML/CSS question. If you lack the knowledge how to properly use those to achieve what you want, then maybe you should go read some tutorials on the matter first.

Comment: Try to add "style= display: inline-block;" to the h1 and h4 tags. There tags are blocks with full width, thats why the text shows under it.

Comment: For sanity, you're probably going to want to use Thymeleaf to generate your email messages, see [here](https://github.com/gmazza/tightblog/blob/12efd9dd9f3e68aed032cc133758cabfab91ef42/src/main/webapp/thymeleaf/emails/PendingCommentNotice.html) and [here](https://github.com/gmazza/tightblog/blob/12efd9dd9f3e68aed032cc133758cabfab91ef42/src/main/java/org/tightblog/business/MailManagerImpl.java#L238) for an example.  After that, it looks like you have just some vanilla questions on CSS and tabular layout that can be asked/answered separately.